# angular universal Cannot find name 'expect'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I need some help.
When I run npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
I get the following errors

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
TS2304: Cannot find name 'fail'.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! simplestate@0.0.1 webpack:server: `webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the simplestate@0.0.1 webpack:server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-12T08_57_37_447Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! simplestate@0.0.1 build:ssr: `npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the simplestate@0.0.1 build:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-12T08_57_37_479Z-debug.log
```

Comment: search your code for the words 'expect', 'it' and 'fail'

Answer (score 0):

In your tsconfig.json file, add these lines:

```js
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "e2e",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
```

This tells the compiler to ignore node_modules and e2e directories and any .spec files when compiling. I ran into this issue in Angular 8 after integrating Universal and those methods are found in the spec files of each component.